# Draw only specific axis text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following **data.table**:

```r
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
dt = data.table(id = paste0('ID_', 1:2000),
                group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 400),
                value = as.logical(rbinom(2000, 1, prob = 0.25)))
```

I would like to create a **ggplot** like below, where on the y-axis only the text labels, for which the variable `value` equals `TRUE` are drawn, without removing the other data. Additionally, it would be best, if the text labels won't overlap (if possible), hence using all the empty y-axis space.

```r
# draws all categorical id values
ggplot(dt, aes(y = reorder(id, -value), x = group, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: For the first 100 cases:

```
dt1 <- dt %>% 
  mutate(ylabel = ifelse(value==TRUE, id, "")) %>% 
  slice(1:100)

ggplot(dt1, aes(y = reorder(id, -value), x = group, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = dt1$ylabel
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]